# Using str_replace( )

Tags: php

how to remove
`onmousedown="return curwt(this, 'http://www.example.com/2009/07/content.html')"` using `str_replace( )`, i know how to use this string but can not understand the way to configure this string to remove `onmousedown="all content"` in this way.
I have tried in this way: `$result = str_replace("onmousedown''", " ", $result);` 
But it will not work.. any idea?

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` instead. `str_replace()` doesn't let you use wildcards like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want to use a regular expression

```
$result = preg_replace('/onmousedown=".*?"/', '', $result);
```

Or if it can be both apostrophes and quotes:

```
$result = preg_replace('/onmousedown=("|\').*?\1/', '', $result);
```

Comment: thanks, one more question is it ok> `$result = str_replace( 'href="', "href='http://site.com/visit.html?", $result);`

Comment: It's okay in that it will work..  I can't say whether it will do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use str_replace for this, because it can only replace pre-defined strings, no wildcards.

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) for this.