# Using str_replace or preg_replace?

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace the window.location link function to window.open in my template..

The HTML looks like:

```
<div onclick="window.location="http://www.website.com/""</div>
```

I've tried following examples from the below links without any luck...

[Add _blank to all external links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162016/add-blank-to-all-external-links)
[Using str_replace( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304256/using-str-replace)

What should I use str_replace or preg_replace?

Comment: First of all fix your HTML, quotes are wrong there, either escape them or use single quotes

Comment: You have to use `preg_replace`, since you're not just doing a simple string replacement, you need to match the pattern `window.location="blah"` and add something before and after it.

Comment: refer this to know the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245513/php-preg-replace-preg-match-vs-php-str-replace

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace`:

```
$new_line = preg_replace('/window.location=([\'"][^"\']*[\'"])/', 'window.open($1)', $line);
```

Comment: single quotes in regex need escaping